# R packages for deriving spatial clusters from origin-destination matrix

Tags: r, clustering, transportation, origin-destination, flow

I have a matrix of origin-destination flows and I am trying to figure out the best way to derive X number of functional spatial clusters from the data. I haven't done this particular type of analysis before, but can I treat the O-D matrix as a dissimilarity matrix and simply use a hierarchical clustering algorithm as discussed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49232/self-organizing-maps-and-spatially-constrained-clustering-in-r)? What, if anything, do I need to do to the O-D matrix if I'm going to go this route?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a rambling set of resources/publications I have collected on the topic.

- Ratti, Carlo, Stanislav Sobolevsky, Francesco Calabrese, Clio Andris, Jonathan Reades, Mauro Martino, Rob Claxton & Steven H. Strogatz. (2010) Redrawing the map of Great Britain from a Network of Human Interactions. [PLoS ONE 5(12)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0014248). Article is open access from link.
- [Flow mapping with graph partioning and regionalization](http://www.spatialdatamining.org/software/flowmap) software from the Spatial Data Mining and Visual Analytics Lab.
- Hennemann, S. and Derudder, B. (2012) [An alternative approach to the calculation and analysis of connectivity in the world city network](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1206/1206.6214.pdf). Hennemann has an article in the Journal of Maps in which you can see [more of the end result](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/suppl/10.1080/17445647.2012.753850/suppl_file/tjom_a_753850_sup_30538329.pdf).

I haven't dug into any of them enough to give real firm advice about whether or not they can be performed in R. The Flow mapping software and the Hennemann articles use slightly different and novel techniques (so I'm guessing would take custom code), the Ratti article though just looks like it uses some regular definitions from other networking theories (the Hennemann and Guo articles take some pain to make sure the clustering obeys spatial configurations).

Those articles are about clustering regions of inter-connections rather than clustering flows (which it sounds like you want), but some articles on clustering the flow lines themselves exist. For an example see Phan, Doantam, Ling Xiao, Ron Yeh, Pat Hanrahan & Terry Winograd. (2005) Flow Map Layout. In Information Visualization, 2005. [INFOVIS 2005. IEEE Symposium: 219–224](http://doi.ieeecomputersociety.org/10.1109/INFOVIS.2005.13).| [PDF here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/flow_map_layout/flow_map_layout.pdf) You can see similar interactive layouts in the [D3.js hierarchical edge bundling](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1044242), or here is a really cool example of it as well, [Global Dependency Explorer](http://cephea.de/gde/beta) via [visual complexity](http://www.visualcomplexity.com/vc/project.cfm?id=726). Unfortunately D3.js does not appear to support native flow data like you have, but may be something to keep on the radar (if that is something you want).

Comment: Thanks for these links. I was interested in the second approach, which I believe is an implementation of the [Intermax](http://www.ejtir.tbm.tudelft.nl/issues/2013_01/pdf/2013_01_00.pdf) approach. I believe that Bostock (D3) was involved in the creation of Protovis, which had flow map creation. However, I'm less interested in a pretty visualization and more interested in being able to derive lists of node regions. The context is deploying resources to manage and balance assets within each region, if that helps.

Comment: It isn't clear to me @scuerda how the intermax approach relates to edge bundling (or the other networking measures). Nice maps and statistics should be complements of one another. Post back if you receive a better answer (or derive one yourself). From your further description it isn't 100% clear to me that you really want clustering, but I've no doubt clustering may be useful to the end goal - good luck.

Comment: Hi Andy, sorry, I didn't mean to imply that good looking visualizations weren't useful. As I understand the Intermax approach, it is a way of defining regions based on flows / connectivity between a large number of nodes. As such, it produces clusters of functionally connected nodes. In any case, I'll post back with my solution. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

if you're prepared to ditch the graph paper i've seen the HOPACH package used to map flows between clusters of regions as nodes

e.g. outputs see slide 15
http://www.segra.com.au/segra11ConfProc/presentations/tuesday/concurrents/JonesWarwick.pdf